# How to put an exception for a variable placed in a loop which call and executes a separate Url each time the variable changes in a python script?

Tags: python, loops, exception, keyerror

I want to put an exception in the loop where the value station= item[101]. Basically the loop runs for the values of "station" and this "station" id value changes the url1 every time. Only for the value of station where the id is 101 he url1 doesn't return anything, so eventually the loops breaks and i get a `KeyError: 'data'` for the "output['data']". 
The loop should be in such a form that it will ignore the station=101 value and move on to the next value and call the url with the next value in "str(station)" defined in the url1.

```js
import urllib2
import json

url="http://ewodr.wodr.poznan.pl/doradztwo/swd/swd_api.php?dane={%22token%22:%22pcss%22,%22operacja%22:%22stacje%22}"
# open the url 
json_obj= urllib2.urlopen(str(url))
output= json.load(json_obj)
 
station_res= output ['data'] ['features']
for item in station_res:

 station= item['id']
 
url1="http://ewodr.wodr.poznan.pl/doradztwo/swd/meteo_api.php?dane={%22token%22:%22pcss%22,%22id%22:" +str(station)+ "}"  
 json_obj2= urllib2.urlopen(str(url1))
 output2= json.load(json_obj2)
 for item2 in output2 ['data']:
  print output2['data']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catching an exception is something that can be done with a [Try/Except](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Here is what it looks like with your code:

```
import urllib2
import json

url="http://ewodr.wodr.poznan.pl/doradztwo/swd/swd_api.php?dane={%22token%22:%22pcss%22,%22operacja%22:%22stacje%22}"
# open the url
json_obj= urllib2.urlopen(str(url))
output= json.load(json_obj)

station_res= output ['data'] ['features']
for item in station_res:
    station= item['id']
    url1="http://ewodr.wodr.poznan.pl/doradztwo/swd/meteo_api.php?dane={%22token%22:%22pcss%22,%22id%22:" +str(station)+ "}"
    json_obj2= urllib2.urlopen(str(url1))
    output2= json.load(json_obj2)
    try:
        for item2 in output2 ['data']:
            print output2['data']
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

This will catch any KeyError exception and continue on.